# Variable not detected as array

Tags: php

I am trying to create a document register code (Still functions have not been written) and I tried to do an echo to check that my code is working fine. Unfortunately, it is apparently not working, as I get an error of $tag not been an array when it actually is.
The error that I get is:

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\Intranet\Argumentarios\admin\uploader.php on line 37

> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Intranet\Argumentarios\admin\uploader.php on line 38
> Tag

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\Intranet\Argumentarios\admin\uploader.php on line 37"

The code is:

```
class Paquete{
    //Variable
    public $tag = array();
    //Funcion
    public function guardar($tag){
        $this->tag = $tag;
    }
    public function grabar($tag){
        //INSERT....
        echo "Tag". $this->tag . "<br/>";
    }
    public function ciclos() {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($this->tag); $i++){
            Paquete::grabar($this->tag[$i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$Packete->guardar($tag1);` sets `$this->tag` to the string in `$tag1`, so it's not an array any more.

Comment: Also, `grabar()` should echo `$tag`, not `$this->tag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`guardar()` should push `$tag` onto the  `$this->tag` array, not replace the array with a single tag.

Also, `grabar` should not echo `$this-tag`, it should echo the `$tag` argument. And it should be declared static since it doesn't need to use `$this`.

```
class Paquete{
    //Variable
    public $tag = array();
    //Funcion
    public function guardar($tag){
        $this->tag[] = $tag;
    }
    public static function grabar($tag){
        //INSERT....
        echo "Tag". $tag . "<br/>";
    }
    public function ciclos() {
        foreach ($this->tag as $tag) {
            Paquete::grabar($tag);
        }
    }
}
```